# How to perform a recursion in a directory avoiding overlaps

Tags: salt-stack

Using the SaltStack states, I'm trying to set file and directory permissions recursively with some exclusion.

I have a file structure like the following:

- /dir1/file1
- /dir1/file2_untouch
- /dir1/dir2/file3
- /dir1/dir2/file4_untouch
- /dir1/dir3/file5
- /dir1/dir3/file6

With the following state almost everything **(except the exclusion)** is executed correctly but the **same overlaps appear at each execution** because */dir1* set 0644 and */dir1/dir3* set 0755 again.

```
config_dirs:
  file.directory:
    - user: user1
    - group: user1
    - dir_mode: '0755'
    - exclude_pat: file*_untouch
    - recurse:
      - user
      - group
      - mode
    - names:
      - /dir1:
        - file_mode: '0644'
      - /dir1/dir3:
        - file_mode: '0755'
```

I would like this results:

- Set the permission 0644 to every files in */dir1/dir3*;
- Leave unchanged the files with pattern *file*_untouch*;
- Set the permission 0644 to every other files;
- Set the permission 0755 to every other directories;

Answer (score 0):

The `exclude_pat` option of `file.directory` only applies to the [`clean`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.directory) functionality.
In fact the `file.directory` state module does `chmod/chown` actions only as a side job and [isn't very good at it](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/3471).

To achive the desired `chmod/chown` actions in a stateful fashion, you can work around the `file.directory` limitations like this:

```
config_dirs_dir_ownerships:
  cmd.run:
    - name: "find /dir1 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \\; -exec chown user1:user1 {} \\;"
    - onlyif: "find /dir1 -type d -not \\( -perm 755 -a -user user1 -a group user1 \\) |grep ."

config_dirs_file_ownerships:
  cmd.run:
    - name: "find /dir1 -type f -not -name 'file*_untouch' -exec chmod 644 {} \\; -exec chown user1:user1 {} \\;"
    - onlyif: "find /dir1 -type f -not -name 'file*_untouch' -not \\( -perm 644 -a -user user1 -group user1 \\) |grep ."
```

If this is too "hacky", you should consider writing a simple custom module for it. 
`os.walk` should do the job and really isn't that hard to implement. Next best documentation for custom modules: https://pyholodeck.readthedocs.io/en/latest/first_module.html

Comment: Yes it's too hacky. I edited the file module, now I would send it to SaltStack creators.